# C# Listing ZIP file contents - using ZipArchive Class

Tags: c#, zip, .net

I would like to obtain a list of contents in a ZIP file using the 'ZipArchive' class.

I am using an example from MSDN:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO.Compression;
using System.IO.Compression.dll;

namespace Zip_Extractor
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            using (FileStream zipToOpen = new FileStream(@"c:\users\exampleuser\release.zip", FileMode.Open))
            {
                using (ZipArchive archive = new ZipArchive(zipToOpen, ZipArchiveMode.Update))
                {
                    ZipArchiveEntry readmeEntry = archive.CreateEntry("Readme.txt");
                    using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(readmeEntry.Open()))
                    {
                            writer.WriteLine("Information about this package.");
                            writer.WriteLine("========================");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However, I get the error

> 'Namespace for 'ZipArchive could not be found'.

I can confirm the 'Target framework' for the application is .NET Framework 4.5.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Did you add `System.IO.Compression.dll` as a reference?

Comment: Adding this gives me the error "the type or namespace name 'dll' does not exist in the namespace System.IO.Compression". I think this may be a .NET version issue.

Answer (score 3):

Add references to `System.IO.Compression` and `System.IO.Compression.FileSystem`.

Check David Anderson's blog: http://www.danderson.me/dotnet/zipfile-class-system-io-compression-filesystem/

Hope this Helps!

Comment: I have added these references. However I am getting the error the type or namespace name 'FileSystem' does not exist in the namespace System.IO.Compression. Any ideas?

Comment: When I select Project>{Project Name} Properties on the Application tab - the 'Target framework' is .NET Framework 4.5. I am using Visual Studio Pro 2012.

Comment: Try to set Full trust for the application.

Comment: No joy with 'This is a full trust application'. - I still get Error 1 The type or namespace name 'dll' does not exist in the namespace 'System.IO.Compression' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Comment: You can try use DotNetZip instead. It has the same function as the ZipFile class.

Comment: @JHarley1, did you try add them manually from project References ? It worked from me and i posted the screen shot of it. Hope that helps !

Answer (score 0):

Right click references, add a reference to framework assemblies System.IO.Compression and System.IO.Compression.FileSystem.  Include using System.IO.Compression; and ensure you're using .NET Framework 4.5.

Answer (score 0):

I'm late on this but it may help someone...

Add references to the files mentioned in other answers:

- System.IO.Compression
- System.IO.Compression.FileSystem

It probably will not work after adding those, so go into their properties and mark each ones "copy local" setting to "True".

Did the trick for me.  :)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and looked for these namespaces in `Assemblies -> Framework:`
Just add the namespaces: `System.IO.Compression & System.IO.Compression.FileSystem`.

Here is the screen shot to make understanding/things easier:

[image]